# Assign a odbcReader to a dataSet

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable, dataset, sqldatareader

I had executed a stored Procedure

```
Dim conStr As String = "Dsn=dat;database=dat;option=0;port=0;server=localhost;uid=root"
Dim con As New OdbcConnection(conStr)
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("dat.selectRowCount", con)
con.Open()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startIndex", 5)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endIndex", 15)
Dim reader As OdbcDataReader
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While reader.Read
'Some operations performed
End While
```

if i need to add this `reader` to a `DataTable` means

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("adm_ttemp")
dt.Load(reader)
```

But how can i assign this reader to a `DataSet` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are looking for a  `odbcReader to a dataSet` assignment? you can directly read query result to a `dataset` as mentioned in the above answer?

```
    Dim conStr As String = "Dsn=dat;database=dat;option=0;port=0;server=localhost;uid=root"
    Dim con As New OdbcConnection(conStr)
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("dat.selectRowCount", con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startIndex", 5)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endIndex", 15)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    '<---- lines to be noticed 
    Using AD As New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
        AD.Fill(DS)
    End Using
```

You can call a stored procedure in following way, just try

```
    Dim conStr As String = "Dsn=dat;database=dat;option=0;port=0;server=localhost;uid=root"
    Dim con As New OdbcConnection(conStr)
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("dat.selectRowCount", con)
    con.Open()
    '<----
    Dim callString As String = "CALL dat.selectRowCount(5,15)"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = callString
    '<-----
    Dim dlist As New DataList
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Using AD As New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
        AD.Fill(DS)
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to change your approach a little, and use an [`OdbcDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as follows:

```
Dim conStr As String = "Dsn=dat;database=dat;option=0;port=0;server=localhost;uid=root"
Dim con As New OdbcConnection(conStr)
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("dat.selectRowCount", con)
con.Open()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startIndex", 5)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endIndex", 15)
Dim DS as new DataSet
Using AD as new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
  AD.Fill(DS)
End Using
' Perform your operations on the DataSet
```

Comment: where is `dataset`? only `dataTable` and `DataAdapter` is here na?

Comment: @NeethuSoman My mistake, updated the answer. (I normally use DataTables in my work rather than DataSets, hence the confusion)